# Using Inline Assembly to update internal system registers

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I'm tying to use inline assembly in a project that i'm currently working on. The project is about building a simple OS from scratch.

I've made it to the part where i begin writing the kernel code and the screen driver.

The problem is in the screen driver and i think it is exactly in the code which saves/retrieves the screen cursor (the blinking one) into/from internal registers.

This is where inline assembly is used in my code.

I have separated the inline assembly part from the screen driver in a separate file in order to test it's functionality properly.

Here is the test.c :

```
# include <stdio.h>

// scree device I/O ports
# define REG_SCREEN_CTRL 0x3D4    
# define REG_SCREEN_DATA 0x3D5

unsigned char port_byte_in ( unsigned short port ) {

    // A handy C wrapper function that reads a byte from the specified port
    // "= a " ( result ) means : put AL register in variable RESULT when finished
    // " d " ( port ) means : load EDX with port
    unsigned char result ;
    __asm__ ("in %%dx, %%al" : "=a" (result) : "d" (port));
    return result ;

}

void port_byte_out ( unsigned short port , unsigned char data ) {
    // " a " ( data ) means : load EAX with data
    // " d " ( port ) means : load EDX with port
    __asm__ ("out %%al, %%dx" : :"a" (data) , "d" (port));
}

unsigned short port_word_in ( unsigned short port ) {
    unsigned short result ;
    __asm__ ("in %%dx, %%ax" : "=a" (result) : "d" (port));
    return result ;
}

void port_word_out ( unsigned short port , unsigned short data ) {
    __asm__ ("out %%ax, %%dx" : :"a" (data) , "d" (port));
}

void main (){
    int i = 10;

    printf("%d\n",i);
    port_byte_out ( REG_SCREEN_CTRL , 14);
    port_byte_out ( REG_SCREEN_DATA , ( unsigned char )( i >> 8));
    port_byte_out ( REG_SCREEN_CTRL , 15);


    port_byte_out ( REG_SCREEN_CTRL , 14);
    int j = port_byte_in ( REG_SCREEN_DATA ) << 8;
    printf("%d\n",j);
    port_byte_out ( REG_SCREEN_CTRL , 15);
    j += port_byte_in ( REG_SCREEN_DATA );
    printf("%d\n",j);
}
```

by running test.c it gives me :

```
10
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i was expecting some value rather than a segmentation fault.

Any help would be greatly appreciated , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` and `OUT` instructions are privileged. You cannot generally call them from a user-space executable in Linux.

You can use the [`ioperm()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioperm) or [`iopl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/iopl) system calls to give your executable the right to access I/O ports directly. Note that these system calls both require your executable to be running as root.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but actually i'm using this code in the scope of booting my simple OS it self .. meaning that in this case i have all the privileged that i need right ?

Comment: The error message you posted (`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`) indicates to me that you are running this code under a UNIX-based operating system (probably Linux), not within your custom OS.

Comment: and i tried using iopl(0) running as super user , it only printed "10" then exited normally

Comment: True , i tried running this test.c on linux to test it's functionality.

Comment: `iopl(0)` is normal privileges. You'd need to use `iopl(3)` to get access to I/O ports.

Comment: thanks @duskwuff. this worked out after using iopl(3) now it produced "10 0 0"